# When will the weights and biases in feed-forward network becomes or approach zero?

Tags: neural-network

It can cause problems in training when weights and biases in feed-forward network becomes or approach zero. But we are not discussing vanishing gradients here, but rather about under which conditions exactly will the weights and biases of layers approach zero during the feed-forward/the forward pass?